# SQL Server Geo MakeValid

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, geospatial

An error thrown by SQL Server says that the MakeValid method may cause points to shift "slightly." I have been looking to see what, exactly, "Slightly" means here, but have not found anything.

Can someone please clarify what exactly this method considers "slight?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .MakeValid() function simply tries to shift the geometry's coordinates by the minimum degree required to make the geometry valid as is defined by OGC standards.

I'm not sure that the actual term of "slight" is quantifiable, but you will notice that almost all coordinates shift to some degree, even if it's at the 6th, 7th, 8th or greater decimal place.

I try wherever possible to ensure that the geometry is valid and the function not required, because when used the inherent nature of floating-point precision means every X and Y value ends up carrying 13 decimal places which adds a lot of "weight" to the geometry in terms of storage and bandwidth.  There are however plenty of sources that require it's use to conform.

It's not a definitive answer, but I'm not sure one is available, nor really needed.

Comment: Thanks. I will be using the function for fairly simple polygons, mostly squares, or, at least, quadrilaterals. Basically it will be used to identify points within the defined polygon. So, the user will give 4 points, and the system will locate known points already stored as geography points intersected by the polygon. Basically I'm using MakeValid in case the user passes the points clockwise. I dont anticipate the user passing decimal values with more than five or so decimal places. In you opinion, would the shift really have much impact here?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  At the equator (so at it's largest), the 5th decimal place represents 11 metres on the latitude so beyond that the change is minimal.  Can I assume you're using SqlGeometry if you're using `MakeValid()` on SQL 2008?  You could consider simply passing the 4 coordinates back to the server, using `STUnion()` to stick them together (`var geom = p1.STUnion(p2).STUnion(p3).STUnion(p4);` and then using `var box = geom.STConvexHull()` to create a box that "joins" them up in the simplest polygon allowed.  This way, you needn't worry about the impact of `MakeValid()`.